# Powershell Invoke-Webrequest Body Rest-API

Tags: powershell, rest

I wanted to add a Body in a Invoke-Webrequest

I am a newbie in Powershell Rest API Request...

So here is the example what i need to create it in a Body into a Powershell Scipt:

```
Body:
{
   "select":[
      "SERVICE.ID"
   ],
   "parameter":[
      {
         "field":"SERVICE.NAME",
         "value":HOSTNAME 
      }
   ]
}
```

How can i convert these into a Powershell Body ??

Answer (score 1):

You can use a JSON Body directly with `Invoke-Webrequest`

```
$Body = @'
{
   "select":[
      "SERVICE.ID"
   ],
   "parameter":[
      {
         "field":"SERVICE.NAME",
         "value": "HOSTNAME"
      }
   ]
}
'@

Invoke-WebRequest -Uri [...] -Method Post -Body $Body
```

And you can convert it to PS Object using `ConvertFrom-Json` like this:

```
$Obj = $Body | ConvertFrom-Json

$Obj

select       parameter                              
------       ---------                              
{SERVICE.ID} {@{field=SERVICE.NAME; value=HOSTNAME}}
```